# cakephp 1.3 xmlns serialize an array without the :

Tags: xml, cakephp, namespaces

In cakephp you can serialize an array into an xml document. I need the namespace to say xmlns="my/ns/url".

You can add the option

```
'namespaces'=>array('name'=>'url')
```

but this returns xmlns:name="url" and this does not work.

Does anyone know how to get xmlns="my/ns/url" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://api13.cakephp.org/class/xml#method-XmladdNamespace

For an example see

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/tests/cases/libs/xml.test.php#L1354

Comment: This is not the right function. This does the same thing that the above function does. It adds xmlns:name= but I need xmlns=